# Accessing ES6 super properties

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, super

So I was messing around with ES6 classes when I saw something surprising:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    speak(sound) {
        console.log(sound);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    constructor(name, age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
    speak() {
        super.speak("Woof! I'm " + super.name + " and am " + this.age);
    }
}
```

Then, I created my dog:

```
var mydog = new Dog("mydog",3);
mydog.speak();
```

Now this prints

```
Woof! I'm undefined and am 3
```

So my question is, why is `super.name` undefined? I'm expecting it to be `mydog` in this case.

Comment: `super` can only be used to access properties on the prototype. Using `this.name` you are assigning to the *instance* and so always need to access it using `this`

Comment: Why can't you access the super attribute but assign a value?

class a {
  name = 'jack';
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class b extends a {
  count() {
    super.name = 'Lucy';
    super.speak();
  }
}

new b().count();   // Lucy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`this` in the parent constructor still refers to the dog, so `this.name = name`, sets the property `name` directly on the `Dog` object and not on its parent. Using `this.name` will work:

```
super.speak("Woof! I'm " + this.name + " and am " + this.age);
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't want to be duplicating properties, I'll need to wait 3 minutes before accepting this answer though

Comment: It won't really be duplicated, it will only be created on the Dog itself. If you look at the prototype chain of your dog you will see: `Dog { name: 'mydog', age: 3 } <- Dog {} <- Animal {} <- {}`